# How to have django-oscar alongside other apps?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am trying to add a django-oscar shop to an existing django website.

My problem is that the templates of the two are somehow clashing, such that I can either see the existing website, or the shop, but not both.

Here is the overarching urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from oscar.app import application

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),

    # oscar
    url(r'^shop/', include(application.urls)),
]
```

And in the settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
        ],
        # 'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',

                'main.context_processors.google_analytics'
            ],

            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

If I switch the order of the loaders, either the original website (in app 'main'), or the Oscar shop, can no longer be accessed/viewed. So I'm not sure what esoteric detail I'm overlooking, and the docs don't cover this. Cheers.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong - do the templates fail to load entirely, or does it just render the wrong template? Also, what template structure do you have - what is the name of your base template?

Comment: index.html, inherits from base.html, is a good example. When I access the root with app_directories_loader set first, it loads fine. When I switch loaders, it seems to be showing an index.html that comes from Oscar (which is blank in content, but has an Oscar favicon). So basically rendering the wrong template, somehow they seem to be named the same. Don't know how I'd fix this because Oscar templates names aren't in my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having is that your template names conflict with Oscar's. Oscar has it's own `base.html`, which is what the template loader will find if you list that loader first, instead of your own `base.html`. Django will use the first one it finds.

This is a [known issue with Oscar](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/1378) - unfortunately there is no backwards compatible way to fix it, and so it hasn't been addressed for some time.

Changing Oscar's behaviour is quite difficult so I'd suggest you try and change your template structure instead. Specifically, you should namespace all your app templates. So if your app is called `myapp`, then put the base template in `myapp/templates/myapp/base.html`. You would then refer to this in other templates as `{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}`. Similarly put all other templates in `templates/myapp/`.

This will ensure that your templates do not clash with Oscar's, and the problem should go away.

Comment: Well I'm wondering if I'm making a mistake by using Oscar. It just appeared to be the most popular shop library, but it's striking me as a bit clumsy (frankly so is Django though, I already have to write 'main/static/main' for static files and then --collectstatic them). I'll have to do some more research into other simpler libraries if they exist and are popular.

I'm wondering if perhaps I should just bite the bullet and change to Rails.

Comment: *I already have to write 'main/static/main' for static files* - not too sure what you mean by that, but it doesn't sound like you're doing it right. Also `collectstatic` is only required for deployment in production. If you have set up your project correctly then it should not be needed in development.

Comment: Yeah I burned enough hours trying to have it run on dev on my machine the same as in production, so now I just do it exactly the same for both. Collectstatic gathers all of the apps' /static files into the root /static dir. So if two apps have a static file with the same name, it's a clash. Hence the main/static/main stuff, which was actually per the documentation.

Comment: But thanks for the answer though, it fixed it. People aren't following the DRY rule, unfortunately, when they design stuff. Even when they explicitly say they will. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial06/.